# find the label's for attribute value that has the following text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below HTML Code and need to get the label's for attribute value where text = 'Complaint'; I couldn't find a proper way to get this done and this because the items inside the span are loading dynamically. Therefore I cant just get the value with the generated id hence I need to find the ID using the label. If that label exist i.e. `<label for="CSSMLCall_call_outcome_types_1">Complaint</label>`. I need to get its for `attr` val.

Is this a possible thing to do with Jquery?

```
<span id="CSSMLCall_call_outcome_types">
<input type="checkbox" name="CSSMLCall[call_outcome_types][]" value="5238" class="session_outcome_chk_list" id="CSSMLCall_call_outcome_types_0"> 
<label for="CSSMLCall_call_outcome_types_0">Client didn’t engage</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="CSSMLCall[call_outcome_types][]" value="4287" class="session_outcome_chk_list" id="CSSMLCall_call_outcome_types_1"> 
<label for="CSSMLCall_call_outcome_types_1">Complaint</label>

</span>
```

Instead of `$("#CSSMLCall_call_outcome_types_4").is(":checked")`, i need to find the id using the label and then do the same.

Any prompt reply is highlight appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var id = $('label:contains("Complaint")').attr('for');
```

Comment: Thanks for this as well. this is quiet easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

```
var id = $('label').filter(function(){
             return $(this).text().trim() == 'Complaint';
         }).attr('for');
```

References:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: This has fewer side effects, but I'm guessing pXL's solution will be good enough for OP's use case (in which case I think that's more readable).

Comment: Probably, but I'm not a *huge* fan of 'good enough' where, on later updates, the text could be updated to 'Complaints about...' (for example). I'm fussy. =)

Comment: `.trim()` will not work for `< IE9` You should use `$.trim()` instead

Comment: @DavidThomas: Fair enough, but if we're going to build logic that depends on text content then that is a dangerous change to make either way. You could *at least* equally well imagine a scenario where the text was changed to "Complaints about..." and that was still the intended select target.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for an answer with Javascript only use `htmlFor`:

```
var id = label.htmlFor;
```

Like:

```
var id = document.getElementById("myLabel").htmlFor;
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var id = $('label[for]').filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text()) == 'Complaint'
}).attr('for')
```

Comment: Hi Arun, tnx for the quick reply. i am getting this error. TypeError: $(...).fitler is not a function
 

var id = $('label[for]').fitler(function(){

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative to using jquery written in POJS.

HTML

```
<span id="CSSMLCall_call_outcome_types">
<input type="checkbox" name="CSSMLCall[call_outcome_types][]" value="5238" class="session_outcome_chk_list" id="CSSMLCall_call_outcome_types_0"> 
<label for="CSSMLCall_call_outcome_types_0">Client didn’t engage</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="CSSMLCall[call_outcome_types][]" value="4287" class="session_outcome_chk_list" id="CSSMLCall_call_outcome_types_1"> 
<label for="CSSMLCall_call_outcome_types_1">Complaint</label>
</span>
```

Javascript

```
/*jslint maxerr: 50, indent: 4, browser: true */
/*global console, jQuery, $ */

(function () {
    "use strict";

    function walkTheDOM(node, func) {
        if (node && node.nodeType) {
            if (typeof func === "function") {
                func(node);
            }

            node = node.firstChild;
            while (node) {
                walkTheDOM(node, func);
                node = node.nextSibling;
            }
        }
    }

    function escapeRegex(string) {
        return string.replace(/[\[\](){}?*+\^$\\.|]/g, "\\$&");
    }

    function filterElementsByContains(elements, string) {
        var toStringFN = {}.toString,
            text = toStringFN.call(elements),
            result,
            length,
            i,
            element;

        if (text !== "[object NodeList]" && text !== "[object Array]" && !($() instanceof jQuery)) {
            return result;
        }

        result = [];
        if (typeof string === "string") {
            string = new RegExp("^" + escapeRegex(string) + "$");
        } else if (toStringFN.call(string) !== "[object RegExp]") {
            return result;
        }

        function getText(node) {
            if (node.nodeType === 3) {
                text += node.nodeValue;
            }
        }

        length = elements.length;
        i = 0;
        while (i < length) {
            text = "";
            element = elements[i];
            walkTheDOM(element, getText);
            if (string.test(text)) {
                result.push(element);
            }

            i += 1;
        }

        return result;
    }

    function getAttribute(node, attribute) {
        var undef;

        if (!node || !node.nodeType || !attribute || typeof attribute !== "string" || !node.attributes || node.attributes[attribute] === undef) {
            return undef;
        }

        return node.attributes[attribute].nodeValue;
    }

    var labels = document.getElementsByTagName("label");

    console.log(getAttribute(filterElementsByContains(labels, "Complaint")[0], "for"));
    console.log(filterElementsByContains(labels, "C"));
    console.log(filterElementsByContains(labels, /C/));
    console.log(filterElementsByContains(labels, /client/i));
    console.log(filterElementsByContains(labels, "Client"));
    console.log(filterElementsByContains($("label"), /Client/));
}());
```

Output

```
CSSMLCall_call_outcome_types_1
[]
[label, label]
[label]
[]
[label]
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/eXyfe/)

With these functions, you can supply a `NodeList`, an `Array` of Elements, or a `jQuery` object as the `elements` parameter. The `string` parameter can be either a string or a regex.

It will return an Array of filtered elements that either contain an exact match for the supplied string, or for the matched regex.

I believe this is more powerful/flexible than the jquery [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector which can only filter by whether the text is contained directly within the selected element.

These functions should be cross-broswer friendly, although I can't test every browser out there, or every possible condition.

I have also create a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-contains-vs-hand-crafted) so that you can compare the jquery method vs this answer.

Anyway, I thought I'd share this alternative with you, and someone else may also find it useful.