# Using JavaScript, I want to use XPath to look for the presence of a string, then refresh the page based on that

Tags: javascript, xpath

I am working with GreaseMonkey so using JavaScript.

## Is string present?

When [this HTML page](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5546881/stack-overflow-hiya-alreet/news-bulletin.html) loads, I want to look for a string in a specific place.

The specific place: XPath: `/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/TABLE[1]/TBODY[1]/TR[3]/TD[1]/TABLE[1]/TBODY[1]/TR[1]/TD[1]/P[1]/B[1]`

( contained in this place: `<b>Newsletter Issue Date: June 20th, 2013</b>`)

## Action

If the string `June 20` is there, then do nothing. (No action required)
If the string 'June 20` is **not** there, then do a page reload.

Comment: Consider whether /html/body/table would be sufficient for your XPATH locator.  It would be a lot more robust against document changes.  Would work as long as that string wouldn't appear 'elsewhere' within the top level table.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Sure, the string will only exist in the one place, if present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want something a little more generic, then you could use something like this.

HTML

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><p><b>Newsletter Issue Date: June 10th, 2013</b></p></td>
            <td><p><b>Newsletter Issue Date: June 11th, 2013</b></p></td>
            <td><p><b>Newsletter Issue Date: June 12th, 2013</b></p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><p><b>Newsletter Issue Date: June 13th, 2013</b></p></td>
            <td><p><b>Newsletter Issue Date: June 24th, 2013</b></p></td>
            <td><p><b>Newsletter Issue Date: June 25th, 2013</b></p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><p><b>Newsletter Issue Date: June 20th, 2013</b></p></td>
            <td><p><b>Newsletter Issue Date: June 21st, 2013</b></p></td>
            <td><p><b>Newsletter Issue Date: June 22nd, 2013</b></p></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
/*jslint maxerr: 50, indent: 4, browser: true */

(function () {
    "use strict";

    function walkTheDOM(node, func) {
        if (node && node.nodeType) {
            if (typeof func === "function") {
                func(node);
            }

            node = node.firstChild;
            while (node) {
                walkTheDOM(node, func);
                node = node.nextSibling;
            }
        }
    }

    function escapeRegex(string) {
        return string.replace(/[\[\](){}?*+\^$\\.|]/g, "\\$&");
    }

    function filterElementsByContains(elements, string) {
        var toStringFN = {}.toString,
            text = toStringFN.call(elements),
            result,
            length,
            i,
            element;

        if (text !== "[object NodeList]" && text !== "[object Array]" && !($() instanceof jQuery)) {
            return result;
        }

        result = [];
        if (typeof string === "string") {
            string = new RegExp("^" + escapeRegex(string) + "$");
        } else if (toStringFN.call(string) !== "[object RegExp]") {
            return result;
        }

        function getText(node) {
            if (node.nodeType === 3) {
                text += node.nodeValue;
            }
        }

        length = elements.length;
        i = 0;
        while (i < length) {
            text = "";
            element = elements[i];
            walkTheDOM(element, getText);
            if (string.test(text)) {
                result.push(element);
            }

            i += 1;
        }

        return result;
    }

    if (filterElementsByContains([document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0]], /June 20/).length) {
        alert("exists");
    }
}());
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/xXbsJ/)

You can see some other examples of its use [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17170959/592253)

If you must convert XPATH to CSS selectors then take a look at this [GIST](https://gist.github.com/Dither/1909679)

Comment: Ooh, interesting; **thanks**.  How can I flip it so that it does the action if `June 20` **isn't** there.  (obviously I would replace `alert("exists")` with `location.reload();`

Comment: In other words, I want the script to stop/finish if `June 20` is there. If it isn't, I want it to refresh the page. [Sorry, very elementary questions, I'm very new to this!]

Comment: `if(!filterElementsByContains(...).length) {`

Comment: thanks, that's pretty sweet. Curious [re: `/June 20/` ] : how come we're using `/` instead of `"`? Sorry if that's a stupid question!1

Comment: Because in this case that parameter is a [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) as we are checking if the pattern exists within a text node, use a string if want you want an exact match of a text nodes content when using this function.

Comment: This works a treat, but for some bizarre reason, it **stops working** when the following unrelated scripts are enabled: [Greasekit a](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5546881/stack-overflow-hiya-alreet/greasekit-a.txt) and [greasekit b](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5546881/stack-overflow-hiya-alreet/greasekit-b.txt). It's a mystery to me - does anyone know? **Sorry for the obscure, unrelated question, it's kind of a brainteaser**

Answer (score 1):

You can flip your selector to a css selector and then use [`document.querySelector(selector);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector)

```
var xpath = '/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/TABLE[1]/TBODY[1]/TR[3]/TD[1]/TABLE[1]/TBODY[1]/TR[1]/TD[1]/P[1]/B[1]',
    selector = xpath.replace(/\/([a-z]+)\[([0-9]+)\]/gi, function(_, tag, num) {
        num--;
        return tag + ':nth-child(' + num + ')>';
    }).slice(0, -1);

var element = document.querySelector(selector);
```

When you got the element you can use [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML) to get the html of the specified node.

```
var mySearch = 'June 20';
if ( element.innerHTML.indexOf(mySearch) == -1 ) {
    // the string isn't present
};
```

Comment: I can't get this to work :(. Is the top line supposed to end in a comma, and not a semicolon?